# After installing PHPUnit with composer it has errors

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit

Composer fresh installed PHPUnit. When i try to type in terminal VSCode "phpunit" it gives me error. To install PHPUnit i used command "composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^10"

```
PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 285

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 285
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(239): PHPUnit_Util_Getopt::getopt(Array, 'd:c:hv', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(138): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php on line 80

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(239): PHPUnit_Util_Getopt::getopt(Array, 'd:c:hv', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(138): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Getopt.php on line 80
```

I tried reinstalling.

Checked vendor folder and there are some files with errors in folder vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Output there is Facade.php

in line 16 "use PHPUnit\TextUI\Output\Default\ProgressPrinter\ProgressPrinter as DefaultProgressPrinter;" and Default is underlined

And also in vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Output/Default every file is with errors too

Comment: Which version of PHP and PHPUnit do you use? Are you sure this problem is really related to Composer itself?

Answer (score 0):

I found sollution for now. I need to type in terminal

> vendor/bin/phpunit test.php

Then it works!